# Import caffe error

Tags: python, caffe

i compiled caffe successfully in my ubuntu machine but cannot import in python.

Caffe is installed /home/pbu/Desktop/caffe

i tried adding the /home/pbu/caffe/python path  to sys.path.append, still not working

i am trying to import caffe

```
root@pbu-OptiPlex-740-Enhanced:/home/pbu/Desktop# python ./caffe/output.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./caffe/output.py", line 13, in <module>
    import caffe
  File "/home/pbu/Desktop/caffe/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver
  File "/home/pbu/Desktop/caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver
ImportError: No module named _caffe
```

Comment: Probably already solved, but the path you say you added to the path is different from the one where you say Caffe is installed.

Comment: Also, the path caffe expects is different from the usual default. Check that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This happens when you have not run `make` for the python files separately.

Run `make pycaffe` soon after running `make` in the Caffe directory.

You may have to set the path to the python library correctly in `Makefile.config`

Comment: How do you find your python path?

Comment: For python library paths, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358451/make-pycaffe-fatal-error-python-h-file-not-found

Comment: make to pycaffe.py file ? why is this ? why it is not pre-compiled ? (I am windows user)

Comment: How can I install caffe in a dedicated virtual environment?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the above best answer. After you run `make` for python files by running `make pycaffe` where you ran your previous `make`s. Then you have to export that python path by running `export PYTHONPATH=<path-to-caffe>/python`. You can choose to run this everytime before running a python code which utilizes caffe or add it to your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use the `cmake-gui` for `making` Caffe. There you need to set the Python paths to the Anaconda-python:

```
PYTHON_EXECUTABLE <path_to_anaconda_home>/bin/python2.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY <path_to_anaconda_home>/include/PYTHON2.7
PYTHON_LIBRARY <path_to_anaconda_home>/lib/libpython2.7.so
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build caffe and pycaffe using the command:

```
cd $FRCN_ROOT/caffe-fast-rcnn
make -j8 && make pycaffe
```

and before the compilation, you should create a `Makefile.config` file and set the corresponding library path, such as python.

More details are presented on the web: [bgirshick/py-faster-rcnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn).

What's more, when I run the "Beyond the demo" section, it seams that if I Create a symlink of the folder "VOCdevkit" as "VOCdevkit2007" which turns out to be "can't find the dataset". So, I change the folder name as "VOCdevkit2007", and it runs well.

Comment: this answer is quite specific to the "faster RCNN" implementation

Answer (score 0):

I posted my Caffe install notes (my architecture: Arch Linux x86_64 | Intel i7 CPU ...) in an Anaconda Python 2.7 virtual environment here:

[Caffe Installation Notes](https://gist.github.com/victoriastuart/fb2cb22209ccb2771963a25c06221213)

```
https://gist.github.com/victoriastuart/fb2cb22209ccb2771963a25c06221213
```

I also encountered the (downstream) "Import caffe error," for which I needed to resolve my $PYTHONPATH to complete the make compilation and get Caffe finally installed, and also to be able to import it (in Python).