# make pycaffe fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found

Tags: python, macos, compiler-errors, neural-network, caffe

I compiled caffe on a mac running OSX 10.9.5  and I know trying to compile pycaffe. When I run make pycaffe in the caffe root folder, I get:

```
CXX/LD -o python/caffe/_caffe.so python/caffe/_caffe.cpp
python/caffe/_caffe.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include <Python.h>  // NOLINT(build/include_alpha)
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [python/caffe/_caffe.so] Error 1
```

how can I fix this?

Perhaps is something wrong with Makefile.config. How do I know what is my PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Look in the include folder of your Python installation.

Comment: Hi @MalikBrahimi, could you be more specific please?

Comment: if i do  `cd /usr/local/bin/python' it tells me "not a directory. If I go to /usr/local/bin/ within finder, I see a python icon, but no folder.

Comment: Look in the folders mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819661/python-location-on-mac-osx).

Comment: Ok! using     which Python     i get     /Users/Andrea/anaconda/bin/Python.

Comment: What do I do now @MalikBrahimi? Do i need to change this line "PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/local/include/python2.7 \
                /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include"
in Makefile.config?

Comment: Inside the include folder there should be a `Python.h` which you can copy into your C++ project.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I dont have a C++ project. this question is specifically about installing compiling pycaffe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83036/discussion-between-andrea-di-biagio-and-malik-brahimi).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the comments, I see that you use Anaconda. In [`Makefile.config`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/Makefile.config.example), you should uncomment the lines dedicated to Anaconda:

```
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's in root.
# ANACONDA_HOME := $(HOME)/anaconda
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
        # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7 \
        # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include \

# We need to be able to find libpythonX.X.so or .dylib.
PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
# PYTHON_LIB := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib
```

`Python.h` is in `$(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7` as you can see running `sudo find / -name 'Python.h'`.

Comment: I've just realized that I only partially uncommented those anaconda-related  PYTHON_INCLUDE lines... Ouch, had to re-make. Thanks a lot for pointing out the details!

Answer (score 3):

I met this problem too.
I have set the `PYTHON_INCLUDE` PATH

```
    PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
    $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7
```

But it still can't find the `Python.h`

So I just give the include path manually to the compiler as follows:

```
    export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/woolawren/anaconda2/include/python2.7/:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

if you don't use anaconda2, you can use:

```
    export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python2.7:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

I have successfully done "make pycaffe" by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a tedious Caffe install on Arch Linux; hopefully my install notes (link below) will help others.

While specific to my Caffe install, those notes address the "Python.h" install error (this Question), as well as a downstream issue mentioned in another SO question,

[Import caffe error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177298/import-caffe-error).

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177298/import-caffe-error
```

My gist file (notes):

[Caffe Installation Notes](https://gist.github.com/victoriastuart/fb2cb22209ccb2771963a25c06221213)

```
https://gist.github.com/victoriastuart/fb2cb22209ccb2771963a25c06221213
```

Answer (score 0):

I uncommented the below code in Makefile.config

```
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.5m \
                 /usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
```

Then did sudo make pycaffe.

It worked.