# Caffe Framework :Importing Error

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, caffe, pycaffe

[image]I followed the instructions from "https://gist.github.com/nikitametha/c54e1abecff7ab53896270509da80215" and  installed caffe framework.

[image]

But ,when I import caffe from some other directory ,it is showing this error

[image]

caffe framework was installed but, it still shows the import error -

> No module named caffe

How to solve this issue?

Thank you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to import caffe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623259/unable-to-import-caffe)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `~/caffe/python` to your `$PYTHONPATH`. either

```
~$ PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/caffe/python python
>>> import caffe
```

**Or** you can do it inside python

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, '~/caffe/python')
>>> import caffe
```

Alternatively, you can modify your `~/.bashrc` file and fix `PYTHONPATH` environmet variable there

Comment: @Anna so it works? I don't understand what you are trying to show in your screen shots.

Comment: No yaar, It's not working, I tried your code. but still it shows import error No module named caffe

Comment: can you tell me the path of bashrc file?