# Error message: ImportError: No module named _caffe

Tags: python, macos, terminal, caffe, pycaffe

I tried to install that [install Caffe Tutorial](http://christopher5106.github.io/big/data/2015/07/16/deep-learning-install-caffe-cudnn-cuda-for-digits-python-on-mac-osx.html), but I am block at this line in the tuto: ./tools/demo.py

I havre this error message:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-OlostA:fast-rcnn OlostA$ ./tools/demo.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./tools/demo.py", line 19, in <module>

    from fast_rcnn.config import cfg

  File "/Users/OlostA/Technologies/fast-rcnn/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>

    from . import train

  File "/Users/OlostA/Technologies/fast-rcnn/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 10, in <module>

    import caffe

  File "/Users/OlostA/Technologies/fast-rcnn/tools/../caffe-fast-rcnn/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver

  File "/Users/OlostA/Technologies/fast-rcnn/tools/../caffe-fast-rcnn/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>

    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver

ImportError: No module named _caffe
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ImportError: No module named _caffe` mean `ImportError: No module named _core` where is default `src` path ? `Distributable` or `Standalone module` ?

Comment: @dsgdfg Where can I find the src path ?

Comment: Don't miss any step on your_installing_link, you missed `env` and `prefix` arguments.

Comment: @dsgdfg I think I checked, but all my path seems to be correct. I followed the tuto very carefully. It seems that It doesn't find the path to _caffee, very strange...

Comment: Line 13 on `pycaffe.py` say : `from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver, NCCL, Timer` , **how to call compiled `exec` if not create one?**. Check `/Users/OlostA/Technologies/fast-rcnn/tools/../caffe-fast-rcnn/python/caffe/` you will be se an `_caffe.cpp`, but need one `_caffe.pyc` ? I think there's a setup phase you skipped. Modules that use hardware iteration will not work as copy paste. Your system needs to check the compilation and competence of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import caffe error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177298/import-caffe-error)